# Summarize selected entries in a data set with a query

Tags: r, for-loop, summary, cbind

I am still pretty new to R and try to summarize data in a specific way. To illustrate it here, I am using the weather data from the nasaweather package. As an example, I would like to get the average temperature on a specific day, and display it for the 3 origins and the 12 months contained in this data set.

I think I can ge it done using the following code, where I specify the day I am interested in, create an empty data frame to be filled in, and then run a for loop through the months where I calculate the average temperature for each origin, cbind them with the month, and rbind them to the data frame. Finally I adjust the column names and print out the result:

```
library(nasaweather)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

query_day = 15
data_output <- data.frame(month = numeric(),
                EWR = numeric(), 
                JFK = numeric(),
                LGA = numeric())

for (i in 1:12) {
  data_subset <- weather %>%
    filter(day == query_day, month == i) %>%
    summarize(
      EWR = mean(temp[origin == "EWR"]),
      JFK = mean(temp[origin == "JFK"]),
      LGA = mean(temp[origin == "LGA"]))
  data_output <- rbind(data_output, cbind(i, data_subset))
  rm(data_subset)
}

names(data_output) <- c("month", "EWR", "JFK", "LGA")
print(data_output)
```

In my hands this yields the following:

```
   month     EWR     JFK     LGA
1      1 39.3725 39.0875 38.9150
2      2 42.1625 39.3425 42.9050
3      3 37.4150 36.7775 37.3025
4      4 50.1275 48.1550 49.2050
5      5 58.8725 55.7150 59.1575
6      6 70.7825 70.2950 71.5700
7      7 86.9900 85.1225 87.2000
8      8 69.2075 69.0725 69.9425
9      9 60.6350 61.2125 61.7375
10    10 59.8850 58.3850 60.5150
11    11 45.7475 45.1700 49.0700
12    12 32.4950 38.0975 34.0325
```

which is exactly what I want. I just figured that my code seems to be far too complicated and would like to ask whether there is an easier way to get this job done?

Comment: You can just use the aggregate function and then reshape `a <- aggregate(temp ~ month + origin, weather, mean); reshape(a, id = 'month', ...)`

Comment: Thanks @Dirk, yet if I get it right this yields the average temperature for the whole month, and not the average temperature on a specific day. Is there a way to specify that within the aggregate function?

Comment: Ah missed that `a <- aggregate(temp ~ month + origin, weather[weather$day == query_day, ], mean); reshape(a, id = 'month', ...)`

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much @Dirk, 15 lines -> 1 line, way to go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a variety of problems with your code... but the main one is the fact that you didn't group_by first. As soon as you include that, this becomes easy peesy. Look at my comments to your code first, and then the finalized code at the bottom:

```
library(nasaweather) ## Wrong package
# library(magrittr) ## not needed, it's called by dplyr
library(dplyr)

query_day = 15
#  data_output <- data.frame(month = numeric(), ## We won't need to specify this explicitly 
## (but you are right that you should specify this in a for loop. Go one step
## further by actually telling the data.frame how many rows to expect. 
## But not in this case cause we won't use for loop)
                        #  EWR = numeric(), 
                        #  JFK = numeric(),
                        #  LGA = numeric())

for (i in 1:12) { ## You don't need to do a for loop... you can do it with the summarize_by function.
  data_subset <- weather %>%
    filter(day == query_day, month == i) %>%
    summarize(       ## Before doing summarize, you need a group_by to say what to summarize_by
      EWR = mean(temp[origin == "EWR"]),
      JFK = mean(temp[origin == "JFK"]),
      LGA = mean(temp[origin == "LGA"]))
  data_output <- rbind(data_output, cbind(i, data_subset)) ## If you're doing the group_by, this step isn't required. 
  # rm(data_subset) ## You don't have to remove temporary datasets...
## When the for loop ends, they are automatically removed.
}

names(data_output) <- c("month", "EWR", "JFK", "LGA") 
print(data_output) 

################### Better code:
library(nycflights13) ## your the package you waant is nycflights13... not nasaweather
library(dplyr)

query_day = 15

weather %>%
  filter(day == query_day) %>%
  group_by(month) %>%
  summarize(
      EWR = mean(temp[origin == "EWR"]),
      JFK = mean(temp[origin == "JFK"]),
      LGA = mean(temp[origin == "LGA"])) -> data_output

data_output
```

Yields:

```
> data_output
# A tibble: 12 × 4
   month     EWR     JFK     LGA
   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1      1 39.3725 39.0875 38.9150
2      2 42.1625 39.3425 42.9050
3      3 37.4150 36.7775 37.3025
4      4 50.1275 48.1550 49.2050
5      5 58.8725 55.7150 59.1575
6      6 70.7825 70.2950 71.5700
7      7 86.9900 85.1225 87.2000
8      8 69.2075 69.0725 69.9425
9      9 60.6350 61.2125 61.7375
10    10 59.8850 58.3850 60.5150
11    11 45.7475 45.1700 49.0700
12    12 32.4950 38.0975 34.0325
```

Comment: Thanks @Amit for all these helpful comments, so much to learn! I tried it with "group_by" first but never got it to work, guess I must have done something terribly wrong. However, when I run the 11 lines of your improved version (## Better code:) I do not get back a 12 x 4 tibble, but only one line: `1 54.47438 53.86937 55.12938` with one value each for `EWR JFK LGA`, which I guess is the mean for all 12 months. Any idea what I am (again) doing wrong here?

Comment: Sounds strange... clear your console, or even restart RStudio and try again? I just re-tried and it works correctly.

Comment: Restarting RStudio did the job, now it works for me as well, thanks!